# How can I disable bottom left preview URL?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website, I need to somehow disable the bottom left URL, like the do [here](http://youmatter.accademiadellusso.com/en/blend), but I don't know how to.

screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Pretty sure you can't as it is one of the few ways to see where a link actually goes.

Comment: I have seen a lot of websites who disabled this.

Comment: That's a WebGL website using canvas

Answer (score 5):

This result, although I personally disagree because the paths are not stored on search engines, can be obtained using tags like SPAN, DIV, IMG, B and then make the page change through javascript.

```js
$('.link').click(function(){
  location.href = $(this).attr('data-url');
});
```

```css
.link{
  background: red;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span class="link" data-url="https://stackoverflow.com">Link span</span>

<span class="link" data-url="https://stackoverflow.com">Link span</span>

<span class="link" data-url="https://stackoverflow.com">Link span</span>

<span class="link" data-url="https://stackoverflow.com">Link span</span>
```

Comment: Why are you using jQuery to do this?

Comment: if you want you could also do without, but I think that jQuery, when it is possible to use it, is a great help for us programmers .. :)

Answer (score 4):

That's the status bar in Chrome and you have no controls over it

https://superuser.com/questions/239202/turn-off-the-link-hover-statusbar-in-google-chrome

The website you're refering to in the question is made using WebGL and it's not using the classic `<a>` html tag.